# Using CryptoSwift framework AES encryption with ECB and pkcs7 IN SWIFT4

Tags: swift, encryption, cryptojs

IN swift I am trying to encrypt text same as `CryptoJS` encryption. But both are not same here I share with you URL, I need to do the same encryption in Swift. Please help me, here I attach my code also. 
[Demo CryptoJS encryption](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crypto)
in this URL we are using `CryptoJS` encryption with `ECB` and `pkcs7`. Same code I am doing in ios but not the same

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CryptoSwift
class CryptoViewController: UIViewController {

 let KEY = "0123456789123456"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         self.aesCBC_Encrypt(AES_KEY: KEY, payload: "Hello World!")
    }
    func aesCBC_Encrypt(AES_KEY: String,payload: String) -> String {
        var result = ""
        do {
            let key: [UInt8] = Array(AES_KEY.utf8) as [UInt8]
            let iv = AES.randomIV(AES.blockSize)
            let bytes = payload.bytes
            let aes = try! AES(key: key, blockMode: ECB(), padding: .pkcs7)
            //let encrypted = try aes.encrypt(Array(self.utf8))
            let encrypted = try aes.encrypt(bytes)
            print("encrypted: \(encrypted)")
            result = encrypted.toHexString()
            print("AES Encryption Result: \(result)")
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

From my code, I am getting this Result

```
AES Encryption Result: 1b8019c2add38f33de9099aefd5369f5
```

But when I am try to Encryption from CryptoJS, Then I am getting this Result

```
 Encrypted Text:
Aeoo7GP6b4l/Pdxz2RS+qA==
```

Comment: The IV is generated randomly for each `let iv = AES.randomIV(AES.blockSize)` call

Comment: You are using a random IV in Swift while a fixed one in CryptoJS. Also, the final result is converted to hexString in Swift while not in CryptoJS.

Comment: Would you please share with me code for this solution .